# How do I stream an archive file with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I'm interested in streaming .zip/.rar/etc archives as they are straight from memory, not archiving them on the fly via a Node module [like this one](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver). Does this kind of stream always have to be transformed? Does it have to unzip the archive before handing over to writable, which archives it again?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding but if you want to stream ALREADY zipped files,
you can just use a readable stream. The `fs` module makes it very easy to create readstreams from files.

For Example:

```
     fs.createReadStream('my.zip').pipe(myWriteStream);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. In Chrome I get an empty file downloaded (named after the URI for some reason), event though I've used `Content-Type:application/zip`.
https://gist.github.com/nosille/75d86797962152a658a6

Comment: Well have you tried isolating anything in your code to see if the stream is the problem? Because you CAN definitely stream archives as is.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nosille/3e299126296fc26e0dc8. It doesn't get any simpler. When visiting home a weird file named "download" (17 Kb) starts downloading automatically.

Comment: Well with express i just streamed a zip using `fs.createReadStream` piped to the res, with mime-type `application/octet-stream` and my browser (chrome) downloaded the file just fine.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nosille/fcfe23ddd095aece4d30. I get the same annoying empty "download" file.

Comment: I have recreated 2 scenarios where I successfully streamed a zip archive with a `readstream` which is in the scope of the question. I feel your issue is with http and what you are attempting to do with streamed content.

Comment: What happens if you also add `Content-Disposition: attachment` to the header in that gist?  Does that fix the issue?